# Pagination in JDBC queries

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, orm

I was wondering what is the standard practice for pagination in case someone is not using an `ORM`?
Use of e.g. `limit` as part of the SQL query?
Also is this problem solved by an ORM out of the box?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the standard practice is to limit the results using some limit clause (which is, unfortunately, non-standard and different for every database).

JPA supports that natively using the [`setFirstResult()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setFirstResult%28int%29) and [`setMaxResults()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults%28int%29) methods, which are translated to the appropriate limit clause in SQL.

Comment: May be I should have written it in the OP, but usually the limit comes from the end-user?E.g. the front-end lets the user select e.g. the number of pages and the size of each page (i.e. num of rows)?

Comment: What does it change? These numbers woud simply become parameters of the SQL query, just like the other parameters like the search criteria.